# Question on Gelfand's Lectures on Linear Algebra, Chapter 1 Section 1.3, Example 3, use of derivatives as coordinates.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

On page 9 of my edition of Gelfand's *Lectures*, he provides a simple basis for a vector space of polynomials, $1$, $t$, $t^2$ ... $t^{n-1}$. The coordinates of the polynomial

$P(t) = a_0t^{n-1} + a_1t^{n-2} + ... + a_{n-2}t + a_{n-1}$

in that space are given as the coefficients of the polynomial.

So far so good...

Then he suggests the basis $1$, $(t-a)$, $(t-a)^2$, etc.

Now when he expresses the polynomial it is in this form:

$P(t) = P(a) + P^{\prime}(a)(t-a) + . . . + (P^{(n-1)}(a)/(n-1)!)(t-a)^{n-1}$,

with coordinates $P(a)$, $P^{\prime}(a)$, etc.

I did enough scratchwork to convince myself that if

$P(t) = a_0(t-a)^{n-1} + a_1(t-a)^{n-2} + ... + a_{n-2}(t-a) + a_{n-1}$

then, e.g., $(P^3(a)/3!)$ yields the coefficient assigned to $(t-a)^3$.

What I'm missing is why Gelfand added this extra bit of algebra, since $P(a) = a_{n-1}$, etc. in this basis.

Comment: Maybe It Is my fault, but i don't understand your question. What is the "extra bit of algebra"? For what i can see he had Simply done a change of basis. In the basis $(t, \cdots,t^{n-1})$ the coefficients are the coefficients of the polynomial, if the basis is $((t-a), \cdots)$ the coefficients are the derivatives

Comment: I don’t understand your question too. The author was just giving an example to illustrate that the same vector can have different coordinates with respect to different bases.

Comment: @Marco what I'm missing is that the coefficients seem to be the same in each basis. That is, if you evaluate $P(a)$, each term with a $(t-a)$ component reduces to zero, so $P(a) = a_{n-1}$, right? And successive derivatives gradually eliminate powers of those components with each derivative leaving another $a_i$ with no $(t-a)$ component, until the $n-1$th derivative which should be, iirc, $(n-1)!a_0$. If you divide that by $(n-1)!$, then you just have $a_0$, right? I'm not trying to point out an error in the text, I'm just trying to understand the steps I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion is given by the fact that the derivatives of the polynomial $P(t)$ are taken w.r.to the old basis

i will change a bit the notation to make easier to write the formulas. I will write
$$P(t)=a_{n-1} t^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_{0}$$
for the polynomial in the basis $(1,t,\cdots, t^{n-1})$and
$$\tilde{P}(t)=b_{n-1}(t-a)^{n-1}+\cdots b_{0}$$
for the polynomial in the new basis. You want to obtain the value of the coefficients $b_i$. using the Taylor expansion of a polynomial (or using that $P(t)=\tilde{P}(t)$) you obtain that
$$
b_i= \frac{P^{(i)}(a)}{i!}
$$
This means e.g. that $b_{0}=a_{n-1} a^{n-1}+ \cdots +a_{0}$, so the coefficients are not the same in general. In particular $b_0=a_0$ iif $a_{n-1}a^{n-1}+ \cdots a_1 a=0$

Think for example to the case of degree $1$ polynomials. If $P_1(x)=a_1t+a_0$ in the basis $(1,t)$ it becomes
$$
\tilde{P_1}(t)=a_1(t-a)+a_1a+a_0
$$

Comment: I don’t see any need for the symbol $\tilde P$. We are just dealing with different power series expansions here, but these expansions are for the same polynomial $P$.

Comment: @user1551 the confusion in the OP is about these different power expansion. using different symbols for different basis expression of the polynomial helps to clarify this doubt. In particular, he thought that $P^{(i)}(a)$ would be the evaluation of the polynomial that i have denoted with $\tilde{P}(a)$

Comment: Thanks! So was the use of derivatives from the first basis as coefficients in the example of the second basis arbitrary? Or is there a deeper reason that I'm missing?

Comment: @RichJensen it is simply a consequence of the choice of the basis. If you do the calculation that are the terms the will appear. This is because polynomials admit a Taylor series expansion around any point, but this is "not important" in the context of understanding how vector spaces work. I think the book simply wanted to show that in different bases the elements of a vector space have different coordinates

Comment: @Marco I'll give it a shot. But I'm changing the letter used for the coefficients. Trying to keep the $a_i$s separate from the $a$ in $P(a)$ makes my head hurt! :) -- but I do see what you're saying. If $a=0$, then the basis $(t-a)$ turns into $t$ and the coefficients also turn into the original coefficients.

Comment: @Marco I'm feeling rather dumb because I can see that the Taylor series expansion works, but I can't figure out why it works. Even though it's not important to the overall context, i feel like this should be more obvious to me than it is.

Comment: @RichJensen the Taylor series of a (analytic) function $f(x)$ around a point $a$ is, by definition: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n$$ For a polynomial this sum is finite and it gives you exactly the expression that you are looking for

Comment: @Marco and there it is. I feel pretty dumb. I knew I was making this more complicated than it needed to be. If I'd actually looked at the formula closely instead of skipping over it looking for information on its application to polynomials, I could have saved us both a lot of time. Thanks for the time and patience!